# Bash script containing clogin not working when executed via php

Tags: php, bash

I created a simple PHP site we would like to use to disable/enable ports on a cisco switch.
I am passing over two arguments (port and action) to a bash script via the php function exec(). For debugging I set those arguments at the end inside the bash script.

The important part of the php function I am calling looks like this:

```
function PortAction($port, $action){
    echo "<hr /> Port:".$port."<br />Action:".$action;
    chdir('/usr/local/icinga-1.7.0/videowand/');
    echo exec('sh /usr/local/icinga-1.7.0/videowand/action2.sh 2>&1',$output, $return);
    echo "Return / Output: ".$return;
    print_r($output);    
}
```

The bash script "action2.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/libexec/rancid/clogin -c "conf t; int Fa0/1; shutdown" 192.168.6.6
```

If i execute the bash script manually (or even the directly the clogin command) as apache user, it all works as expected, the port gets disabled.
But as soon as I call it over the PHP function, I get the output:

> Array ( [0] => no such variable [1] => (read trace on "env(HOME)") [2] => invoked from within [3] => "set password_file $env(HOME)/.cloginrc" [4] => (file "/usr/libexec/rancid/clogin" line 66)

And nothing gets done.
Which indicates some problem with the password entry (as far as I can see). 
Permissions on this file(s) are correct, I guess they have to otherwise it wouldn't work directly inside the shell.
Even tried to change the .cloginrc path using the -f switch, no success.
PHP Safe-mode: Off
Display errors: On

The script takes a while because a telnet connection needs to be opened. This is why I put this into a separate bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the full path to the `sh` binary, like this:

```
echo exec('/bin/sh /usr/local/icinga-1.7.0/videowand/action2.sh 2>&1',$output, $return);
```

I'm assuming `/bin/sh` above, as that is commonly the standard path for sh, but make sure with
 `which sh` command.

`/bin/sh` is a soft link to your shell, which usually is `/bin/bash`, I'm not sure `exec()` can work with soft links of binaries, so if above doesn't works then just use `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`

Comment: Thanks for this, but the output's still the same error, whether I use /bin/sh, /bin/bash or nothing at all (just /usr/local/icinga-1.7.0/videowand/action2.sh)

Comment: Try with system()  `system('HOME=/home/user /bin/bash /usr/local/icinga-1.7.0/videowand/action2.sh 2>&1', $return);`